# How to use dropdown list in html by using bootstrap-3.3.7- dist without using CDN?

Tags: html, css

I have downloaded bootstrap-3.3.7-dist.I am trying to use dropdown list using this.Unfortunately I'm not able to get desired output.The code is written below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="js/bootsrap.js"></script>
</head>
</body>
<div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you certain that you have linked to the file correctly?

Answer (score 0):

**edit**: `<script src="js/bootsrap.js"></script>` check here. misspelling **bootstrap** may be the problem.

you should be sure of importing bootstraps **links** and **scripts** into your html.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: She said that she has ***DOWNLOADED*** bootstrap, and hence the relative linking.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MVDotNet/gomsnr4k/) is it what you require?

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

and also check external resources in left panel for required css and js files.